# Trying to figure out what addEventListeners aren't being triggered

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JS. I have two addEventListeners with anonymous functions and neither seem to work. I have gone through and looked for syntax errors and can't seem to find any. I'm not sure what to look for next. Here is the JS code, please let me know if more info is needed. Thanks!

```js
function setupPuzzle(){
//match all the data cells in the puzzle 
puzzleCells = document.querySelectorAll("table#hanjieGrid td");

//set initial color to be gold
for(var i = 0; i < puzzleCells.length; i++){
   puzzleCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(233,207,29)";

   //set the cell color in response to a mouse down event 
   puzzleCells[i].onmousedown = setBackground;

   //use a pencil image as the cursor
   puzzleCells[i].style.cursor = "url(images/jpf_pencil.png), pointer";
}

//check for puzzle solution
document.getElementById("hanjieGrid").addEventListener("mouseup", 
function(){
   var solved = true;
   for (var i = 0; i < puzzleCells.length; i++){
      if ((puzzleCells[i].className === "filled" && 
          puzzleCells[i].style.backgroundColor !== "rgb(101,101,101)")
         || 
         (puzzleCells[i].className === "empty" &&
          puzzleCells[i].style.backgroundColor === "rgb(101,101,101)"))
         {
            solved = false;
            break;
         }
   }
   if (solved) alert("You solved the puzzle");
});

//create object collections of the filled and empty cells
var filled = document.querySelectorAll("table#hanjieGrid td.filled");
var empty = document.querySelectorAll("table#hanjieGrid td.empty");

//create an event listener to highlight incorrect cells
document.getElementById("peek").addEventListener("click",
function(){
   //display incorrect white cells in pink
   for (var i = 0; i < filled.length; i++) {
      if (filled[i].style.backgroundColor === "rgb(255,255,255)") {
          filled[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,211,211)";
         }
      }

   //display incorrect gray cells in red
   for (var i = 0; i < empty.length; i++){
      if (empty[i].style.backgroundColor === "rgb(101,101,101)") {
          empty[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,101,101)";
      }
   }

   //remove hints after .5 seconds
   setTimeout(
      function () {
         //change pick cells back to white and red cells to gray
         for (var i = 0;  i < puzzleCells.length; i++) {
            if (puzzleCells[i].style.backgroundColor === "rgb(255,211,211)") {
                puzzleCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,255,255)";
            }
            if (puzzleCells[i].style.backgroundColor === "rgb(255,101,101)") {
                puzzleCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(101,101,101)";
            }
         }
      }, 500);
}
);
}
```

Here is the HTML portion. I checked that for spelling mistakes but didn't see any.

```
<body>
   <header>
      <img src="images/jpf_logo.png" alt="Japanese Puzzle Factory" id="logoimg" />
      <nav>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hints</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Competitions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Site Map</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </header>
   
   <section>
      <div id="topButtons">
         <input type="button" class="puzzles" id="puzzle1" value="Puzzle 1" />
         <input type="button" class="puzzles" id="puzzle2" value="Puzzle 2" />
         <input type="button" class="puzzles" id="puzzle3" value="Puzzle 3" />
      </div>
   
      <h1 id="puzzleTitle"></h1>
   
      <figure id="puzzle"></figure>
   
      <div id="bottomButtons">
         <input type="button" id="peek" value="Peek!" />
         <input type="button" id="solve" value="Show Solution" />
      </div>  
   </section>
   
   <aside>
      <h1>To Play</h1>
      <p>
         Click the <span>Puzzle 1</span> through <span>Puzzle 3</span>
         buttons to select a puzzle. A completed puzzle displays a pixelated
         image matching the patterns shown in the row and column 
         headings. To draw the image, click and drag the mouse pointer
         over the grid cells. Mark empty cells by holding down the
         <span>Alt</span> key as you click and drag. To erase your 
         guesses, hold down the <span>Shift</span> key as you click and
         drag.
      </p>
      <p>Stumped? Click the <span>Peek!</span> button to
         highlight your errors. Incorrect filled cells
         will be highlighted in red; incorrect empty cells 
         will be highlighted in pink. Give up?
         Click the <span>Show Solution</span> button to view the
         completed puzzle.
      </p>
   </aside>
   
   <article>
      <h1>About Hanjie</h1>
      <p>
         <strong>Hanjie</strong> is a Japanese logic puzzle 
         played on a table grid. At the top of 
         each column and to the left of each row are sets of numbers 
         that indicate how many cells in that column or row are 
         marked, working from the top down or from left to right.
      </p>
      <p>
         For example, <code>3 8 1</code>
         indicates that there is a block of three 
         marked cells followed by a gap and then another eight marked cells,
         followed by another gap and then one last marked cell. Gaps can 
         be of any length and can only be determined by 
         clues provided for the other rows and columns in the grid.
      </p>
      <p>
         The completed puzzle shows a pixelated image. A hint describing 
         the image is provided with the puzzle. For tips on solving 
         Hanjie, view the <a href="#">Hanjie Strategy page</a>.
      </p>
   </article>
      
   <footer>
      <nav>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Akari</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Divide by Box</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fillomino</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hanjie</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#">Hashiwokakero</a></li>

         </ul>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Heyawake</a></li>         
            <li><a href="#">Hitori</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kakuro</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Katagaku</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Masugo</a></li>
         </ul>   
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Masyu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Oekaki Logic</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shikaku</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sudoku</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Suhai</a></li>
         </ul>  
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Super Sudoku</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tenketsu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tentai Show</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wordoku</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Yajilin</a></li>         
         </ul>              
      </nav>
   </footer>
      
</body>
</html>
```

This is the portion of the JS that has creates the table and has all of the id's/classes

```
function drawPuzzle(hint, rating, puzzle) {
   
   /* Initial HTML String for the Hanjie Puzzle */
   var htmlString = "";

   /* puzzle is a multidimensional array containing the
      Hanjie puzzle layout. Marked cells are indicated by
      the # character. Empty cells are indicated by an
      empty text string. First, determine the number of rows
      and columns in the puzzle */

   var totalRows = puzzle.length;
   var totalCols = puzzle[0].length;

   /* Loop through the rows to create the rowCount array
      containing the totals for each row in the puzzle */

   var rowCount = [];
   var spaceCount;
   for (var i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
      rowCount[i]="";
      spaceCount = 0;

      for (var j = 0; j < totalCols; j++) {
         if (puzzle[i][j] === "#") {
            spaceCount++;
            if (j === totalCols-1) {
               rowCount[i] += spaceCount + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            }
         } else {
            if (spaceCount > 0) {
               rowCount[i] += spaceCount + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
               spaceCount = 0;
            } 
         }    
      }

   }

   /* Loop through the columns to create the colCount array
      containing the totals for each column in the puzzle */

   var colCount = [];
   for (var j = 0; j < totalCols; j++) {
      colCount[j]="";
      spaceCount = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
         if (puzzle[i][j] === "#") {
            spaceCount++;
            if (i === totalRows-1) {
               colCount[j] += spaceCount + "<br />";
            }
         } else {
            if (spaceCount > 0) {
               colCount[j] += spaceCount + "<br />";
               spaceCount = 0;
            } 
         }    
      }

   }

   /* Create a Web table with the id, hanjieGrid, containing
      headers with the row and column totals.
      Each marked cell has the class name, marked; each
      empty cell has the class name, empty */

   htmlString = "<table id='hanjieGrid'>";
   htmlString += "<caption>" + hint + " (" + rating + ")</caption>";
   htmlString += "<tr><th></th>";

   for (var j = 0; j < totalCols; j++) {
      htmlString += "<th class='cols'>" + colCount[j] + "</th>";
   }
   htmlString += "</tr>";

   for (var i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
      htmlString += "<tr><th class='rows'>&nbsp;" + rowCount[i]+"</th>";

      for (var j = 0; j<totalCols; j++) {
         if (puzzle[i][j] === "#") {
            htmlString += "<td  class='filled'></td>";
         }
         else {
            htmlString += "<td class='empty'></td>";
         }
      }

      htmlString += "</tr>";
   }

   htmlString += "</table>";

   return htmlString;
}
```

Comment: add your html code

Comment: When you check `console.log` are there any errors?

Comment: I checked that in the browser and it didn't show anything (if that is what you mean).

Comment: ```document.getElementById("hanjieGrid")``` I don't see element with ID ```hanjieGrid``` in the provided HTML

Comment: @Drag13 I just added the code with that information.